# AngularJS server-side multi-column search

Tags: angularjs, node.js, search

I am building an application in NodeJS and AngularJS.

I am building a multi-column search functionality where the user can type in search keywords into separate searchboxes (at the top of each column) and retrieve the results based on the column.

[image]

So far I have a single searchbox that searches all attributes at the same time.

How can I implement multiple individual searchboxes that will return results based on multiple attributes?

Note: I want to implement this on the server-side for performance reasons. (I know that I can simply use HTML attributes | filter:column1 | filter:column2 but want to avoid this technique if possible).

Here is the code I have so far. I am thinking that I need to pass in some sort of "searchBy" variable that is set on the view and then update the search method to search by multiple query/attribute pairs.

```
//Search service factory
    //Initialize filtered items and get search results
    function search(items, query) {
      this.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(items, function (item) {
        for(var attr in item) {
          if (searchMatch(item[attr], query))
            return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
      return this.filteredItems;
    }

    function searchMatch(haystack, needle) {
      if (!needle) {
        return true;
      }
      return haystack.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    };

//Controller
  vm.filteredItems = vm.search(vm.unfilteredItems, vm.query);

//View
  input(type='text', ng-model='vm.query', ng-change='vm.search(vm.unfilteredItems, vm.query)', placeholder='Search')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by first creating an array of objects for each search box then repeating those boxes in the view with the ng-repeat attribute.

```
//Controller
var vm = this;
var vm.unfilteredItems; //data source query removed for brevity

//Initialize search inputs
vm.search_by_inputs = [
  {search_column: 'id', search_query: ''},
  {search_column: 'requester', search_query: ''},
  {search_column: 'dataowner', search_query: ''}
];

function initSearch() {
  vm.filtered_items = vm.search(vm.unfiltered_items, vm.search_by_inputs);
}

//View
input.input-large.search-query(type='text', value='{{search_by.search_query}}', ng-model='search_by.search_query' ng-change='vm.initSearch()', placeholder='Search')
```

The next step is to loop over the search_by_inputs object in the controller and create a new object with only the inputs that have search values entered into the searchboxes in the view. Then in the search method the built-in "filter" component iterates each item, and inside that loop each of the search terms is checked against that value with the column name that matches the property.

```
/*
 * Create new array of objects with only elements that have search values to optimize loop inside filter
 * @search_by_inputs array of objects each has a key search_column and a value search_query
 */
function optimizeSearchProperties(search_by_inputs) {
  search_by_properties = [];

  for (var i = 0, len = search_by_inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    //If this column input box has query text
    if (search_by_inputs[i].search_query) {
      search_by_properties.push(search_by_inputs[i]);
    }
  }
  return search_by_properties;
}

/*
 * @haystack search item
 * @needle search term
 */
function searchMatch(haystack, needle) {
  if (!needle) {
    return true;
  }

  return haystack.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}

/*
 * Create filtered items object by filtering search results
 * @items original array of objects returned by database query result
 * @search_by_inputs array of objects each has a key search_column and a value search_query
 */
function search(items, search_by_inputs) {
  var search_by_properties = optimizeSearchProperties(search_by_inputs);

  //If there are no search properties input by requester then return all items
  if (search_by_properties.length === 0) {
    this.filtered_items = items;
    return this.filtered_items;
  }

  this.filtered_items = $filter('filter')(items, function (item) {
    var search_result = true;
    //Loop over all search by input textboxes
    for (var n = 0, len = search_by_properties.length; n < len; n++) {
      //If there is no query text
      if (!search_by_properties[n].search_query) {
        //Continue to next element in array
        continue;
        //Else if element has a property that matches search input column name
      } else if (item[search_by_properties[n].search_column]) {
          if (!searchMatch(item[search_by_properties[n].search_column], search_by_properties[n].search_query)) {
            search_result = false;
            break;
          }
      }
    }
    return search_result;
  });
  return this.filtered_items;
}
```

I would be glad to have some feedback on this solution in terms of optimization, performance, technique, etc. Thanks!